# Show that there exists holomorphic $f$ such that $f^2=\frac{\sin z}{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to show that there exists a holomorphic function $f$ on a neighborhood of $0$ such that $f^2(z)=\frac{\sin z}{z}$ on this neighborhood. Furthermore, I have to find the radius of convergence of the power series of $f$ at 0.

My idea is the following: Since $\sqrt{\bullet}$ is holomorphic on $\mathbb{C} \backslash \mathbb{R}_-$ and $\sin(0)/0=1$, by continuity there is a neigborhood $U$ of $0$ such that the image of $U$ by $sinz/z$ is contained in, say, $\{|z-1|<1\}$. Thus, on this neighborhood $U$, $f(z)=\sqrt{\sin z/z}$ is holomorphic. Is this ok?

Now for the radius of convergence of $f$, I'd say that it's $\pi$ because $\frac{\sin(\pi+\epsilon)}{\pi+\epsilon} \in \mathbb{R}_-$. But how do I know that there is no closer "problem", i.e., how do I know whether  there exists $|z|<\pi$ with $\frac{\sin z}{z}\in \mathbb{R}_-$ ?

Comment: It is not true that $\sin(0)/0=1$. Division by $0$ is not defined.

Comment: I think you mean that $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin x}x=1$.

Comment: I'm assuming that by "radius of convergence of $f$" you mean "radius of convergence of the power series of $f$", right?

Comment: Yes, I mean the radius of convergence of the power series. And yes, in this problem $sin(0)/0$ is defined to be $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your idea for the first one looks sound to me.

Concerning the second part, having negative value is not a real problem for the function $\sin z / z$. We can always choose a holomorphic version of $\sqrt{\cdot}$ near any point, *except* the origin. Indeed, what really matters are zeros of $\sin z / z$.

1. If $u(z) := \sin z / z$ has no zero inside $|z| < r$, then we can define $\log u(z)$ by
   $$
   \log u(z) := \int_{0}^{z} \frac{u'(\xi)}{u(\xi)} \, d\xi,
   $$
   where the contour of integration can be any nice curve from $0$ to $z$ inside the disc $|z| < r$. So we can define $\sqrt{u(z)}$ by
   $$
   {\textstyle\sqrt{u(z)}} := \exp(\tfrac{1}{2}\log u(z)).
   $$
2. Zeros of $u(z)$ are exactly $z = \pm \pi, \pm 2\pi, \cdots$. And more importantly, all those zeros are *simple*. Thus there is no way we can define $\sqrt{u(z)}$ near those zeros.

These two arguments show that the radius of convergence of $f(z)$ at $z = 0$ is exactly the modulus of the nearest zero of $u(z)$, which is exactly $\pi$.